Can subqueries be used in st_read()?
The st_read() command from the sf package in R can take SQL queries (see example here) when reading in shapefiles, but I'd like to be able to include a subquery.
For example, there's a shapefile here with US states:
library(sf)

p <- './cb_2018_us_state_20m.shp' #Path
allStates <- st_read(p) #Reads full dataset

#Query for two states
q1 <- 'select * from \"cb_2018_us_state_20m\" where NAME in (\'Oregon\',\'California\')'

twoStates <- st_read(p,query = q1) #Works

How would this work if there was a separate data frame or vector of States that I wanted to include this as a subquery? I've tried (unsuccessfully) various versions of SQL's in operator but it keeps returning syntax errors:
moreStateNames <- c('Oregon','California','Texas') #Vector of state names
q2 <- 'select * from \"cb_2018_us_state_20m\" where NAME in (\"moreStateNames\")'
moreStates <- st_read(p,query = q2) #Fails


Error: Query execution failed, cannot open layer. In addition: Warning
message: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options),
quiet,  :   GDAL Error 1: "moreStateNames" not recognised as an
available field.

dfStates <- data.frame(id=1:3,moreStateNames=moreStateNames) #Dataframe with state names
q3 <- 'select * from \"cb_2018_us_state_20m\" where NAME in (select moreStateNames from \"dfStates\")'
moreStates <- st_read(p,query = q3) #Fails


Error: Query execution failed, cannot open layer. In addition: Warning
message: In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options),
quiet,  :   GDAL Error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error,
unexpected SELECT. Occurred around : m "cb_2018_us_state_20m" where
NAME in (select moreStateNames from "dfStates")

Where am I messing up here? What are my options other than reading the entire shapefile and then filtering it post-hoc?

You need to expand the vector moreStateNames into a comma-separated string in R before submitting the query. Using sprintf saves you some of the hazzle with quotation marks:

    q2 <- sprintf('select * from \"%s\" where NAME in (\'%s\')',
                  "cb_2018_us_state_20m",
                  paste(moreStateNames, collapse = "','")
                  )


results in:

    ## > q2
    ## [1] "select * from \"cb_2018_us_state_20m\" where NAME in  ('Oregon','California','Texas')"


so that:

    ## > moreStates <- st_read(p,query = q2) # Works
    ## Reading query `select * from "cb_2018_us_state_20m" where NAME in ('Oregon','California','Texas')'
    ## from data source
    ## `full\path\to\cb_2018_us_state_20m\cb_2018_us_state_20m.shp' 
    ##   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
    ## Simple feature collection with 3 features and 9 fields
    ## Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
    ## Dimension:     XY
    ## Bounding box:  xmin: -124.5524 ymin: 25.84012 xmax: -93.53094 ymax: 46.26913
    ## Geodetic CRS:  NAD83



Had to flip the single and double quotations on the collapse argument, but other than that it works great: runs in less than half the time

Is there a practical size limit to this solution? I'm getting error messages like this when I try this on a larger dataset (about 1 million features, and I'm trying to get a subset of about 30,000):
GDAL Error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: memory exhausted.

You could try to increase memory allocation or to st_union the results of several smaller imports (although these, in total, might still reach the memory limit).
